# Volume of the intersection of two solid cones

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, volume

I want to calculate the volume of the intersection (overlap) of two solid cones, as shown below. I imagine this must be a known problem but I'm having a hard time finding anything online, so any pointers to the relevant literature or previous threads I might have overlooked are very welcome too.

[image]

Comment: Have you learned how to do volume integrals yet?

Comment: It looks like the two cones have the same conical angle (one is just a shifted copy of the other) - is that the case?